# Execute the limit after the query in a view

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to build a view of a table that applies a limit after the query.

Let me explain: if I create a view like this:

```
--This view dosen't work like I want:
CREATE VIEW [test_view] AS
        SELECT * 
        FROM test_table 
        LIMIT 200
```

And make a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_view 
WHERE testfield = 'a value'
```

This query returns the match in the first 200 items, but what I want is to return the first 200 or less rows that match with `testfield = 'a value'` like if is applied directly at the table in this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_table 
WHERE testfield = 'a value' 
LIMIT 200
```

Is it possible to build a view that work in this form?

Comment: Is there a reason to limit?

Comment: @Isaiah3015 the reason is Patch a old app that crash with a new bigest database, I want to map the result to 500 elements that match the condition if are more the app crach

Comment: Your assumption is that the DB post the LIMIT value won't have a different value. If you are sure that all records are the same then you can LIMIT but I don't recommend it. I recommend that you create a VIEW for all and then on your SELECT do a DISTINCT and see if all your values are the same. You can always LIMIT it that way. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 I want if is posible no modify the app, since selecting in  a view is equal to select in table. and if the field that i want is the 501 using limit at this way dosen't work , but need to protect the app an no return more than 500 fields in the query

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do something like that. You are limiting the no of rows in the view and giving condition on view, which is not correct way. If you want to limit then limit it after getting your desired result.

Comment: I don't limiting the no of rows in the view  i put this by example to explain wath i want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to limit at the VIEW level since SQL has a way to limit these at the Select LEVEL.

```
 CREATE VIEW [Test View] as Select * from [Test Table] Limit 200
```

EDIT: You can always change the value of 200 to something else. Not sure if this helps since you already have this in your sample. The syntax is the same. Perhaps it's just the way you utilize it?

I recommend creating a view that grabs all the result

```
CREATE VIEW [Test View] as Select * from [Test Table]
```

Then letting the users select the number of rows they want

```
 Select * from View LIMIT 200
```

EDIT 2: You can limit at the SELECT level but not on VIEW level unless you want to specify the values being Selected and limiting it based on those selected values. This is just pseudo code but I hope you get the picture

```
Select case when value=a then (Select * from table limit 200)
             when value=b then (Select * from table limit 300)
             when value=c then (Select * from table limit 400)
```

Comment: Thanks but is sqlite no top stament

Comment: Use LIMIT for SQLLITE. Sorry, didnt see this tag. Let me update

Comment: without the `top` youre view example is the same code that i put as example of dosen't work , wath i want to achive is like insert the limit 500  after any query that apply to the table

Comment: I comment up the reason in the question